# Remove specific characters for a specific text via regex in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex, sql-server-2008, regex-group

I am using SQL Server 2008.

Data:

```
AA00012345/99
AX0000045687044/78
XB000077008/12
```

What I need to do is to remove **consecutive zeros at the beginning only** (after a number except 0 is seen, consecutive zeros are allowed) and the **slash (/) chars** from the string in the output by using REGEX.

Expected output:

```
AA1234599
AX4568704478
XB7700812
```

I managed to do it via this query:

```
select dbo.RegexGroup(t.Value,'(?<prefix>\w\w)(?<zeros>0*)(?<beforeslash>\d*)/(?<afterslash>\d\d)', 'prefix') +
       dbo.RegexGroup(t.Value,'(?<prefix>\w\w)(?<zeros>0*)(?<beforeslash>\d*)/(?<afterslash>\d\d)', 'beforeslash') +
       dbo.RegexGroup(t.Value,'(?<prefix>\w\w)(?<zeros>0*)(?<beforeslash>\d*)/(?<afterslash>\d\d)', 'afterslash') 
from table t
```

However, I believe there should be a better and more professional way to handle this issue. Regex usage is a must. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: doesn't work. slightly edited the question btw.

Comment: Tried a replace, couldn't make it work as well. Maybe I am doing it wrong, could u please try it for me with example data in the question?

Comment: are the first two digits constant?  you can take advantage of a cast like this if they are:  SELECT CAST('0000045687044' AS INTEGER)

Comment: Yes, the first two digits are constant, they are always letters.

Comment: if teh last two are also constant then you can do this:  SELECT LEFT('AX0000045687044/78', 2) + CAST(CAST('0000045687044' AS INTEGER) AS VARCHAR(20)) + RIGHT('AX0000045687044/78', 2)

Comment: or a PATINDEX and LEN to get the last part

Comment: That is a good approach, thanks for it. However, regex usage is compulsatory for this issue, but can add it as an alternative answer, I'd upvote.

Comment: Obviously a SUBSTRING is needed too.  I would like to see a REGEX solution too btw.  My approach is rather simplistic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one option. Query divides strings into two parts, first - letters, second - rest part, starting with number. 0 is removed by replacing with space and applying `ltrim` function

```
declare @t table (c varchar(100))
insert into @t
values ('AA00012345/99')
    ,('AX0000045687044/78')
    ,('XB000077008/12')

select
    t.c, q2.p1 + replace(replace(ltrim(replace(q2.p2, '0', ' ')), ' ', '0'), '/', '')
from 
    @t t
    cross apply (select ci = patindex('%[0-9]%', t.c)) q1
    cross apply (select p1 = substring(t.c, 1, q1.ci - 1), p2 = substring(t.c, q1.ci, len(t.c))) q2
```

Output:

```
AA00012345/99         AA12345/99
AX0000045687044/78    AX45687044/78
XB000077008/12        XB77008/12
```

Comment: @ErayBalkanli, missed that part. Added another `replace`.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> DECLARE @v varchar(100);
>
> SET @V = 'AA00012345/99';
> SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(@v, SUBSTRING(@v, PatIndex('%[0]%', @v), 1), ''), '/', '')
>
> SET @V = 'AX0000045687044/78';
> SELECT REPLACE(@v, SUBSTRING(@v, PatIndex('%[0]%', @v), 1), '')
>
> SET @V = 'XB000077008/12';
> SELECT REPLACE(@v, SUBSTRING(@v, PatIndex('%[0]%', @v), 1), '')
>
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> | (No column name) |
> | :--------------- |
> | AA1234599        |
>
> | (No column name) |
> | :--------------- |
> | AX4568744/78     |
>
> | (No column name) |
> | :--------------- |
> | XB778/12         |
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ac0d72adfa3dd77ec4325aeb3706b229)*

Comment: This is good, but it removes all the zeros. I only want to remove the consecutive zeros at the very beginning. Please recheck the expected output in the question.